# Distributed tensorflow cannot colocate nodes /job:master/task:0' and '/job:ps/task:0'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to setup distributed tensorflow with tf.keras model and estimators api. I'm running into issue:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot colocate nodes
>   'Decoder-Word-Embedding/embeddings' and
>   'training/Nadam/gradients/Decoder-Word-Embedding/GatherV2_grad/Shape:
>   Cannot merge devices with incompatible jobs: '/job:master/task:0' and
>   '/job:p
>       s/task:0'
>           Node: Decoder-Word-Embedding/embeddings = VariableV2_class=["loc:@Decoder-Word-Embedding/embeddings"],
>   container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[4259,300], shared_name="",
>   _device="/job:ps/task:0"]]

This is TF_CONFIG I'm running with

> {"cluster":{"master":["localhost:22222"],"ps":["localhost:22223"],"worker":["localhost:22224"]},"task":{"type":"worker","index":0},"model_dir":"/data/models/"}

Here is code running: https://github.com/inc0/github_issue/blob/master/train.py